# In $22$ Randomly assigned letters, what is the probability that at least one of three words will appear?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We write $22$ Different letters in a sequence, each must appear but only once.

The letters are $x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_{22}$.

What is the probability that at least one of the following words will appear: $x_1x_2x_3, x_4x_5x_6, x_7x_8x_9$

---

What I did:

So it's the probability that we will get at least one of the three words in the sequence of $22$ letters, each word built from $3$ Different letters.

Now the probability that one of them will surely appear is:
Choose one of the three words - $\binom{3}{1}$ - put them in the sequence, we have left with $(22-3)$ Letters to order randomly, namely: $19!$ possibilities, now divide that by the total number of sequences of $22$ Different letters, each appear once = $22!$ possibilities

The rationale is that if we surely have $1$ Of the words in the sequence, its enough to gerenty that at least one will be there.

Therefore, I think the probability that at least one word will appear is:

$$
\frac{\binom{3}{1} \cdot 19!}{22!}.
$$

Surely, I am wrong.

I know that usually, questions like this are solved by looking at the complementary probability, namely, the $1 - P$(none of the words appear), yet I didn’t succeed in calculating this $P$ and moreover, why what I did is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Inclusion Exclusion should work here.

Comment: I tried, did $\frac{\binom{3}{1} \cdot 19! + \binom{3}{2}\cdot 16! + \binom{3}{3}\cdot13!}{22!}$ but its not the answer, am I having a mistake? @lulu

Comment: I don't understand your calculation.  Use Inclusion Exclusion to count the strings without any of those triples.  Start with all the strings.  Then subtract those that contain one  bad triple. Then add back those that contain two bad triples, and then subtract off those that contain all three.

Comment: Ah, your calculation has double (and triple) counting.  That is to say, if a string has two or the special triples then your method counts it twice.  You did not apply Inclusion Exclusion, which is designed precisely to eliminate multiple counting.

Comment: Right, understood my bad, but why not: $\frac{\binom{3}{1}\cdot 19! - \binom{3}{2}16! + \binom{3}{3}\cdot 13!}{22!}$ why u said to use also “start with all the strings”, shouldn’t we start with 1 triple substructe 2 and then add 3? Like: $|A \cup B  \cup C| = |A|+|B|+|C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|$? @lulu

Comment: You can do it that way if you want, I was counting the bad strings but you can use the method to count the good strings directly. It's effectively the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what i just wrote is not the correct answer, maybe you see why? @lulu

Comment: I did not check your answer, I was just saying that you could use the method to count either the good strings or the bad strings.  If you are having trouble with the method, I suggest that you start with a simpler example.  Like look at six characters with some specified doubles, or something like that.  Go slowly.  Don't rush to write down an answer.

Comment: the matter is that the $22$ characters make a $22$-tuple, so position of the triplet(s) also count.

Comment: @GCab Thanks, but I am not sure what to do with what you just said, we used exclusion inclusion, what’s wrong? And why the position of the triple is important? Why do i care if its in the middle the start or the end?

Comment: @Alon: because the "Universe" of equi-probable  22! words accounts also for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As lulu indicated in the comments, you have to apply the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.  As G Cab indicated in the comments, the reason your attempt to use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle did not work is that you have to take the position of the words into account.

Let $A$ denote the set of permutations which include the word $x_1x_2x_3$, let $B$ denote the set of permutations which include the word $x_4x_5x_6$, and let $C$ denote the set of permutations which include the word $x_7x_8x_9$.  Then the number of permutations which include at least one of these three words is
$$|A \cup B \cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|$$

$|A|$:  If a permutation includes the word $x_1x_2x_3$, then we have $20$ objects to permute, the word and the other $22 - 3 = 19$ letters.  Since the $20$ objects are distinct, they can be permuted in $20!$ ways.

By symmetry, $|A| = |B| = |C|$.

$|A \cap B|$:  If a permutation includes the words $x_1x_2x_3$ and $x_4x_5x_6$, we have $18$ objects to permute, the two words and the other $22 - 2 \cdot 3 = 16$ letters.  Since the $18$ objects are distinct, they can be permuted in $18!$ ways.

By symmetry, $|A \cap B| = |A \cap C| = |B \cap C|$.

$|A \cap B \cap C|$:  If a permutation includes the words $x_1x_2x_3$, $x_4x_5x_6$, and $x_7x_8x_9$, then we have $16$ objects to permute, the three words and the other $22 - 3 \cdot 3 = 13$ letters.  Since the $16$ objects are distinct, they can be permuted in $16!$ ways.

Hence, the number of favorable cases is
$$\binom{3}{1}20! - \binom{3}{2}18! + \binom{3}{3}16!$$
Dividing by the $22!$ possible permutations of the letters gives the desired probability.

Comment: I think you should subtract the middle term instead.

Comment: @Empy2  Fixed.  Thank you.

Comment: So the problem was that I didn’t count the word itself in the permutation I did, thank you!